# Kde use super key to show desktop

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, kde5

How can I assign the super key ( windows key ) to the show desktop action in Plasma 5.8

By default it shows the application launcher.

Answer (score 1):

So far [ksuperkey](https://github.com/hanschen/ksuperkey) looks the only solution.
The documentation says it is not necessary for plasma 5.8 but actually make the trick.

By default I have `Control + F12` assigned to show desktop action so I  just need to:

- Remove the association `ALT F1` in the application launcher widget ( other wise super will also open this )
- run in a terminal `ksuperkey -e 'Super_L=Control_L|F12'`

If it works you can add this to the startup application

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1478134/925128) is a newer answer, which might make that a duplicate of the above (although I'm not really sure: this question has no accepted answer, while I'm about to mark the answer under the other question as definitive).